# Apps Script copy row value in History Sheet to first empty row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Need help with code.

Hi all! Need help with code... There are goods/services. The data on them changes daily (in the example, the RANDBETWEEN function is used for this). On another sheet, this data is transferred to a line. It is necessary once a day (a trigger is configured for this) to transfer data from this line to the nearest empty line corresponding to the date. I wrote the code in Apps Script, but it transfers only one value to all products. What did I write wrong? Help, good people.

[Link to file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P_f61ZMDqondbN-UzCIRuragvhEBfcwJlXk33QKl58A/edit?usp=sharing)

```
function ProductHistory() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("История данных");
  var value = sheet.getRange('B1:L1').getValues();
  var range = sheet.getRange('B1:L').getValues();
  var lastRow = null;
  var i = 0;
  while(i < range.length) {
    if (range[i][0] !== "") {
      i++;
    } else {
      lastRow = i +1;
      break;
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(`B${lastRow}:L${lastRow}`).setValue(value)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should filter out blank values in the source data before writing to the history sheet. Once you have the data, use `Sheet.appendRow()`. To run the function script daily, create a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers).

You may want to try the [appendValuesToArchiveSheet](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/27095918?msgid=27163801) script with these parameters:

```
// [START modifiable parameters]
var rangeToLog = 'Данные!B2:B';
var sheetToLogTo = 'История данных';
// [END modifiable parameters]
```

The script will append new rows at the bottom of existing data. Your column `A` contains `=IF(A4<TODAY();A4+1;"")` formulas that you will have to delete so that new data can be written immediately below existing data. The script will automatically insert timestamps on the rows it writes.

Comment: I have one question. Is it possible to change timestamps without time.. only date?

Comment: Select column `A` and choose **Format > Number > Date**. Alternatively, use `=arrayformula(datevalue(A2:A))` in row 2 of a free column. Alternatively, modify the `appendValuesToArchiveSheet()` function. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).